# Call to undefined function upload_is_user_over_quota()

Tags: rest-api, block-editor

I have two different multisites:

- www.example.org
- www.example-two.org

On both sites, there are 5 sub-sites.

They're hosted on the same server (that I have setup myself using VirtualMin). All 10 sub-sites share the same parent theme, with different child-themes that has minor variations in them.

I've converted the sites to Gutenberg, - but whenever I upload an image, then I get this error:

`The response is not a valid JSON response.`

... Seen here:

[image: The response is not a valid JSON response]

In the error-log I get this error:

```
[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12345:tid 123456789012345] [client CLIENT_IP:55472] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function upload_is_user_over_quota() in /PATH/TO/FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-attachments-controller.php:808, referer: http://EXAMPLE.ORG/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit
```

Here is the entire stack-trace:

```
[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12345:tid 123456789012345] [client CLIENT_IP:55472] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function upload_is_user_over_quota() in /PATH/TO/FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-attachments-controller.php:808, referer: http://EXAMPLE.ORG/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit
[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12345:tid 123456789012345] [client CLIENT_IP:55472] mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:, referer: http://EXAMPLE.ORG/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit
[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12345:tid 123456789012345] [client CLIENT_IP:55472] mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /PATH/TO/FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-attachments-controller.php(734): WP_REST_Attachments_Controller->check_upload_size(Array), referer: http://EXAMPLE.ORG/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit
[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12345:tid 123456789012345] [client CLIENT_IP:55472] mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /PATH/TO/FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-attachments-controller.php(108): WP_REST_Attachments_Controller->upload_from_file(Array, Array), referer: http://EXAMPLE.ORG/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit
[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12345:tid 123456789012345] [client CLIENT_IP:55472] mod_fcgid: stderr: #2 /PATH/TO/FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(936): WP_REST_Attachments_Controller->create_item(Object(WP_REST_Request)), referer: http://EXAMPLE.ORG/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit
[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12345:tid 123456789012345] [client CLIENT_IP:55472] mod_fcgid: stderr: #3 /PATH/TO/FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(321): WP_REST_Server->dispatch(Object(WP_REST_Request)), referer: http://EXAMPLE.ORG/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit
[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12345:tid 123456789012345] [client CLIENT_IP:55472] mod_fcgid: stderr: #4 /PATH/TO/FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api.php(266): WP_REST_Server->serve_request('/wp/v2/media'), referer: http://EXAMPLE.ORG/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit
[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [pid 12345:tid 123456789012345] [client CLIENT_IP:55472] mod_fcgid: stderr: #5 /PATH/TO/FOLDER/wp-inclu in /PATH/TO/FOLDER/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-attachments-controller.php on line 808, referer: http://EXAMPLE.ORG/wp-admin/post.php?post=30&action=edit
```

It looks like that [others](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/9142) [are](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/9134) [experiencing](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8935) this error as well.

Does anyone know a fix or a work-around to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In digging around this seems to be a bug with WordPress added in 4.9.8. [This patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/43462) seems to have broken attachment uploads over the REST API on Multisite, because it uses a function from a file that isn't loaded for REST requests.

I've reported the bug [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/44864#ticket).

A quick and dirty fix would be to add this to your theme's functions.php file, or a simple plugin:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'upload_is_user_over_quota' ) ) {
    function upload_is_user_over_quota( $echo ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function won't do what it's supposed to do, but it will prevent the fatal error from occurring.

Comment: Thanks so much, for your assistance (and with your help reporting it). The dirty-fix didn't help, though. It gives this error instead (error 500): 
`[DATESTAMP] [fcgid:warn] [PID_INFO] [CLIENT_IP] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare upload_is_user_over_quota() (previously declared in /PATH/TO/SITE/public_html/wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME/functions.php:698) in /PATH/TO/SITE/public_html/wp-admin/includes/ms.php on line 276, referer: VISITED_URL (a non-admin-page)` ... Should I then add the same 'if-function-exists' in the `wp-admin/includes/ms.php`-file temporarily?

Comment: If I add the `if ( ! function_exists( 'upload_is_user_over_quota' ) ) {` around the same function `inside /wp-admin/includes/ms.php` then it works!!! Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Oh weird, I assumed the ms.php file would've been loaded before the theme. Guess not. Obviously editing core is normally a bad idea, but this should be fixed in 4.9.9, so any future update should fix the issue, so losing your changes won't matter.